# Copy html table column values to specified column input

Tags: jquery, html-table

The HTML table below is generated in my PHP code and can have any number of rows, up to circa 500 or more.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Working</th>    
        <th>Non-Working</th>    
        <th>Top Working Rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DX</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4357][1]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4357][2]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kindle</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4358][1]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4358][2]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kindle 2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4359][1]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4359][2]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kindle 2 3G</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4360][1]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4360][2]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kindle 3 3G</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4361][1]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4361][2]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kindle Fire</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4362][1]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="items[4362][2]" value="1.00"></td>
        <td>60.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save Rates"></td></tr>
</table>
```

By clicking on a link or button, I want to copy the values in the 4th column to input values in the 2nd. If the value is "None", the row shouldn't be copied. Preferably, the solution will enable me to pass as parameters the columns to copy from/to but I can adapt if necessary.

Obviously, when working with larger tables, the code could get slow, but some delay is expected by the end-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('tr').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            prc = $this.find('td').eq('3').html();
        if (prc !== 'None') {
            $this.find('td').eq('1').find('input').val(prc);
        }
    });
});​
```

[FiddleSticks](http://jsfiddle.net/psyon001/tsdaS/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("table").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function(i, row) {
        var cols = $(row).find("td");
        if (cols.length > 0 && $(cols[3]).text() != 'None') { /* skip rows with only <th> */
            $(cols[1]).find("input").val($(cols[3]).text());
        };
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/P5cDY/)

Comment: Thanks, works great also. I'd accept your answer also if I could. Will test both for performance on a larger dataset and may revise my accepted solution.